# How we run JavaScript code when page refresh but function still run

Tags: javascript

How we run JavaScript code when  page refresh but function still run.
I want to run this JavaScript code

```
<script>
function abc(){

}
</script>
```

Comment: Just follow it with `abc();` (or move the code inside, outside the function). If you put that in a page it will run every time the page is loaded or refreshed.

Comment: `abc` does nothing, so why run it?

Comment: `<script>
function abc(){

}
abc(); //executes immediately when this script tag is loaded into the page
</script>`

Comment: The question is clear, what happens to a currently executing function, when the user refreshes the page...

Comment: Can you clear up your question? At the moment it is likely to be closed for being unclear.

Comment: If you're talking about what happens to a function which is running when the page gets refreshed, then simply it stops running. The page which was loaded before the refresh, which was its execution environment, no longer exists, so it stops. Simple as that really.

Comment: do you want to know how to get this method running on page load or what happens with `actually` running code after reloading?

Answer (score 1):

You can get function called/executed on page load or refresh.

```
function abc(){
// enter your code
}
```

With JQuery:

```
$(function(){
  abc();
});
```

jQuery using `.ready()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   abc();
});
```

With Normal JS

```
(function(){
  abc();
})();
```

```js
function abc(){
      console.log(Date.now())
    }

    $(function(){
      abc();
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      abc();
    });

    (function(){
      abc();
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: these functions after refresh will end

Comment: `these functions after refresh will end ` just like each other function.....javascript will not be executed longer than your page is active....this answer is an upvote worth (in contrast to your question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ServiceWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to be able to run things in background (after refresh, when offline, or when your browser/tab is closed).